# scala publisher filter

Tags: scala, filter, publisher

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Publisher.subscribe(Sub, Filter) method in Scala. If I understand correctly I can there specify which methods the subscriber notifies and which don't?

Would anyone care to give an example of the syntax of such a filter?

Answer (score 1):

Note that Scaladoc says: `type Filter = (Evt) ⇒ Boolean`. So any function from `Evt` to `Boolean` will do, e.g. `publisher.subscribe(this, _ != null)`.

Comment: but you can you give a more concrete example, e.g. I want only to subscribe to events from the method publisher.doAction() ?

Comment: This depends on what your events looks like. In this case they need to include information on whether they were created in `doAction()` (or more generally, in which method they were created).